Would this question meet the standards?
I'm new here and I don't want to have a start with a question that is not appropriate or better asked at some other site.
The question is about hair color, and I have to explain why I think history might be the right place to ask.
Somewhere (probably on Wikipedia) I have gathered that the people of ancient Sumer referred to themselves as the "black headed" people. This would make no sense if it would refer to skin color. It makes more sense if it referred to hair color.
But then, it would again make no sense if all the people they had contact with had black hair. So, is anything known about the hair color of the people at that time, especially those surrounding Sumer?

The main issue I see here is that this site will probably insist you come up with a much better reference than "Somewhere (probably on Wikipedia) I gathered". In its current form, this is what I call a "Drunk in a bar told me.." question.
Put in the effort to track down a legit source for that assertion, and you might have something.
Its also a good idea to at least see if Wikipedia has anything to say on the subject that is easy to find. This site is (statistically) unusually difficult to ask good questions on. However, this meta answer on citing research has some very good advice on how to ask a question here that, if followed, would probably prevent half of all question closures here. For bonus points (and even better odds), consider reading through the other highly-voted posts there.

Link "Drunk in a bar told me" does not work, but is clear enough. So, the question as such would be OK but would profit from more reliable references.

@GyroGearloose - Interesting. It looks OK to me, and works for me. Anyone else reading this having trouble with that link?

The link works for me.

Link works for me right now ...
